# highlight 3 input text boxes under a div when error using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form and have lots of text fields for ssn. All these ssns fields are having different id's and names. SO now I have created a class for these ssn fields so that validation will be come easy. So instead of having lots of validations for individual ssn fields, I can do class based validation for all the fields together. Below is the html code for the ssn fields

```
<div class="input-container ssndiv">
  <input class="ssn1" id="owner_ssn1" type="text" name="owner_ssn1_name" maxlength="3" style="width:60px" title="Social Security Number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid"/>
  <span class="inline-text">-</span>
  <input class="ssn2" id="owner_ssn2" type="text" name="owner_ssn2_name" maxlength="2" style="width: 60px"/>
 <span class="inline-text">-</span>
  <input class="ssn3" id="owner_ssn3" type="text"  name="owner_ssn3_name" maxlength="4" style="width: 60px" />
</div>
```

Jquery function for validation

```
$('.ssndiv').each(function () {
   $(this).children('.ssn3').blur(function () {
       ssnValidation($(this).parent());
   });
});

function ssnValidation(obj){
      var error= false;
      var input="";

      obj.children('input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('ssn1')) {
            ssnObject.ssn1 = $(this).val();
            input = $(this);
            input.nextAll("ul.error").remove();

        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('ssn2')) ssnObject.ssn2 = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).hasClass('ssn3')) ssnObject.ssn3 = $(this).val();
    });//end of each
     //Here I have the logic for ssn validation and return error varibale true or false
     if(error)
    {
        var title = input.attr('title');
        $('<ul class="error"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>').insertAfter(input.siblings('input').last());
        //$('.ssndiv input').addClass('required');
        input.addClass('required');
        input.siblings('input').addClass('required');
        //input.parent().find('.ssndiv').addClass( "required" );
        returnVal = false;
    }
     else{
         //$('.ssndiv input').addClass('correcr');
         input.parent().find('.ssndiv').addClass( "correct" );
         //input.addClass('correct');
         //input.siblings('input').addClass('correct');
         returnVal = true;
     }
       return returnVal;
  }
```

So here I am iterating through the each of the ssndiv's and checking of validation is correct or not. If the validation returns false, it should display the error and highlight the 3 ssn fields as red. If all 3 fields are correct, then it should remove the error and display green to the 3 fields. I am able to do the validation part correctly. Say for eg, I have provide wrong values for the first 3ssn fields.It displays error and highlight the fields. But if I enter the second ssn field also wrong, then the first highlight is removed. Now only the second ssn is highlight. But I need the first ssn field also to be highlighted if validation is false. But now when the seond field is having error, highlight on the first field is removed. I am not sure how to handle this in the code.
I have put this in the fiddle. Can some body please help me in this?

http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/77/

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing and adding css class dynamically to your object based on validation, define a class for valid input and one for invalid input and remove and add those classes to your object dynamically from your java script function. You can refer below for syntax

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp

Comment: Hi Ashish, that is how I am doing it..dynamically removing n adding the class..but the loop which I am iterating through seems to be confusing..it would be great if u could please check my fiddle..

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/4Pngm/1/

```
$('#test tr').each (function (){
    $(this).find('td:last-child').focusout(function () {
        var $first_td = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:first-child input');
        var $second_td = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(2) input');
        var $third_td = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:last-child input');
        var first_value= $first_td.val().length;
        var second_value = $second_td.val().length;
        var third_value = $third_td.val().length;       
        if (first_value < 3 || second_value <2 || third_value < 4){
        $first_td.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        $second_td.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        $third_td.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        $(this).parents('tr').next().show();
        }else{
        $first_td.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
        $second_td.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
        $third_td.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
        $(this).parents('tr').next().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I am not following your code procedure, this is little bit different from your code.
Please see and check. Let me know is this your requirement or not.

Comment: hi vinothini..Thanks for the reply..Actually it should check for some logic and highlight red if error. Say for eg, I have provided wrong values for the first 3 ssn fields.It displays error and highlight the fields. But if I enter the second ssn field also wrong, then the first highlight is getting removed here. Now only the second ssn is highlighted. But I need the first ssn field also to be highlighted if validation is false. can u please check ?anyway i will implement ur solution and check.

Comment: In my solution if you enter the second ssn field also wrong, then the first highlight won't remove. In my fiddle example please enter values  and check.

Comment: Hi Vinothini..I am telling the first 2 fields as first ssn field and second 3 fields as second ssn field..I think i confused u with my question...

Comment: I am not able to understand your above comment :-(

Comment: Hi Vinothini..I meant the  3 fields in the first row is the first ssn field and the below 3 fields in the second row is the second ssn field. I have provided wrong values for the first row ssn field.It displays error and highlight all the 3 fields. But if I enter the second row ssn field also wrong, then the first row highlight is getting removed here. Now only the second row ssn is highlighted. But I need the first row ssn field also to be highlighted if validation is false..Hope its clear now..

Comment: Ok. Can you give some test data for valid and inValid.